# How to query TFS history for a particular user from the CLI

Tags: visual-studio, tfs

I'm attempting to find all of my TFS commits using the CLI commmand `tf history` (yes I'm limited to the CLI).

I see that TFS has a /user option but it doesn't appear to work. For example if I just look without the filter I'll get a hit such as

```
Changeset User              Date       Comment
--------- ----------------- ---------- ------------------------------
10945     Rocha, John R     9/4/2015   LO-4838 Update label # to 47
```

However when I try the command:

```
tf history . /noprompt /recursive /stopafter:10 /user:"Rocha, John R"
```

it results in

```
Option user requires exactly one value.
```

What am I missing?

Comment: you didn't provide /user:username as required. unless "Rocha, John R" is your username, which I doubt.

Comment: I don't know my username from TFS's perspective. It shows "Rocha, John R" for the user... ergo it should accept "Rocha, John R" AS the user.

Answer (score 1):

The comma in the username is causing an issue because it thinks that there is more than one username specified.

It might work if you try the username instead of the display name - I can't test because mine are the same.

You can find it by running:

```
net user "Rocha, John R" /domain
```

Hopefully, there's a Username returned that doesn't have a "," in it.

Looking at the source code for the TFS Command Line Parser, I cannot see a workaround, the User option is declared as `MultipleValues` style, and the value parser for `MutlipleValues` splits on `,` with no escape sequence I can see - the `tf history` command then validates that only one value can be returned from the user option.

Here's the code from the Parser:

```cs
case Options.Style.MultipleValues:
{
    int num;
    while ((num = argument.IndexOf(',', startIndex)) != -1)
    {
        if (num - startIndex == 0)
        {
            throw new Command.ArgumentListException(ClientResources.ExtraCommaInOption(invokedAs));
        }
        option.Values.Add(argument.Substring(startIndex, num - startIndex));
        startIndex = num + 1;
    }
    if (argument.Substring(startIndex).Length == 0)
    {
        throw new Command.ArgumentListException(ClientResources.ExtraCommaInOption(invokedAs));
    }
    option.Values.Add(argument.Substring(startIndex));
    return;
}
```